android studio activity xml(about tags)
The code worked well ,but it doesn't work now, even though it's the same code. I added and changed the codes of other files to use chaquopy. I got an error about tags.
I removed codes related to version catalog (alias -> id),
added chaquopy block in build.gradle (module).
Changed versions are below:

compileSDK : 34 -> 33
minSdk : 24 -> 31
jvmTarget : 1.8 -> 18
kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion : 1.5.1 -> 1.5.15

Error messages are below:
Start tag has wrong closing tag: 2, 9(9:<application)
Wrong closing tag name: 19, 20
Top level element is not completed: 22 (last line)
Here's the code below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

I appreciate your help.

I don't see anything obviously wrong with this XML. But you've listed a lot of different changes. Try to narrow down which one is responsible:

Undo all the changes.
Make sure the app builds successfully.
Make the changes one at a time until you find the one that causes the problem.

It's also worth trying a clean rebuild (Build > Rebuild Project).
